# Self updating bash script from github

Tags: linux, bash, git, github, self-updating

I am trying to make my script to check if there is an update from my repo in github and then get the updates and replace old code with new one and run the new code “not the old one”. I came up with this but it updates after it finishes

```
self_update() {
    cd $(dirname $0)
    git fetch > a.txt 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    git reset --hard >> a.txt 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    git pull >> a.txt 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null
    rm a.txt
    chmod +x "$(basename $0)"
    cd -
}
self_update
echo “some code”
```

Edit: I found the below code here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365799/shell-script-self-update-using-git/35365800) and it updates my script. However, it goes into a loop and never runs the new or old code, not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")
SCRIPTNAME="$0"
ARGS="( $@ )"
BRANCH="master"

self_update() {
    cd $SCRIPTPATH
    git fetch

    [ -n $(git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH | grep $SCRIPTNAME) ] && {
        echo "Found a new version of me, updating myself..."
        git pull --force
        git checkout $BRANCH
        git pull --force
        echo "Running the new version..."
        exec "$SCRIPTNAME" "${ARGS[@]}"

        # Now exit this old instance
        exit 1
    }
    echo "Already the latest version."
}
self_update
echo “some code”
```

Repeated Output:

```
 Found a new version of me, updating myself...
 HEAD is now at 5dd5111 Update tool
 Already up to date
 Already on ‘master’
 Your branch is up to date with origin/master
```

It does not stop printing the output till i CTRL-C
Output: Executed with: bash -x /opt/script/firstScript -h

```
++ readlink -f /opt/script/firstScript
+ SCRIPT=/opt/script/firstScript  
++ dirname /opt/script/firstScript
+ SCRIPTPATH=/opt/script                                
+ SCRIPTNAME=/opt/script/firstScript
+ ARGS='( -h )'
+ BRANCH=master
+ self_update      
+ cd /opt/script
+ git fetch                                                
++ git diff --name-only origin/master
++ grep /opt/script/firstScript
+ '[' -n ']'                                               
+ echo 'Found a new version of me, updating myself...'
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
+ git pull --force 
Already up to date.  
+ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
+ git pull --force
Already up to date.
+ echo 'Running the new version...'
Running the new version...
+ exec bash -x /opt/script/firstScript '( -h )'
++ readlink -f /opt/script/firstScript
+ SCRIPT=/opt/script/firstScript
++ dirname /opt/script/firstScript
+ SCRIPTPATH=/opt/script
+ SCRIPTNAME=/opt/script/firstScript
+ ARGS='( ( -h ) )'
+ BRANCH=master
+ self_update
+ cd /opt/script
+ git fetch
++ git diff --name-only origin/master
++ grep /opt/script/firstScript
+ '[' -n ']'
+ echo 'Found a new version of me, updating myself...'
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
+ git pull --force
Already up to date.
+ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
+ git pull --force
Already up to date.
+ echo 'Running the new version...'
Running the new version...
+ exec bash -x /opt/script/firstScript '( ( -h ) )'
++ readlink -f /opt/script/firstScript
+ SCRIPT=/opt/script/firstScript
++ dirname /opt/script/firstScript
+ SCRIPTPATH=/opt/script
+ SCRIPTNAME=/opt/script/firstScript
+ ARGS='( ( ( -h ) ) )'
+ BRANCH=master
+ self_update
+ cd /opt/script
+ git fetch
++ git diff --name-only origin/master
++ grep /opt/script/firstScript
+ '[' -n ']'
+ echo 'Found a new version of me, updating myself...'
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
+ git pull --force
Already up to date.
+ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
+ git pull --force
^C
```

Output: Executed with: bash /opt/script/firstScript -h

```
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
Already up to date.
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
Already up to date.
Running the new version...
Found a new version of me, updating myself...
^C
```

Comment: Do you get any output if you run manually, after doing the `pull`, the command `git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH | grep $SCRIPTNAME`?

Comment: I added the output, please check it out

Comment: You have only added the output of your script, not what I asked for.

Comment: if  i do git fetch; git reset --hard; git pull; manually. then, git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH | grep $SCRIPTNAME will not print my script name but If i do not do it manually it  it will output my script name and that make it go into a loop

Comment: So the problem is the git command. Maybe someone with more git experience than I have, can now see what's going on. I would, for testing, put a `git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH` just before the `if` in your script, and add the output to your question.

Comment: You do a `git checkout $BRANCH` before invoking yourself again. Hence on the next iteration, you are on $BRANCH, while on the first iteration, you are not on $BRANCH. I don't know whether this matters, though.....

Comment: Does your script have local changes? The `git pull` would not destroy them, and afterwards `git diff` will still see something modified in the script (I think). Also, even if you get it working, I don't understand the reason of the logic of your approach: If one file (your script) shows diffs, you want to merge changes for all files (git pull), but if some other files shows diffs, you don't want to do this?

Comment: It does not have local changes. I only made changes in github. I am going with this logic because I want to update other files thats why i am using master "as I was told". to get changes for all folders and tools

Comment: So you have to include the result of the `get diff` command and hope that someone with decent git-knowledge sees your question. And, I suggest to add a `git` tag, since the essence of your question is about using git, not bash.

Comment: run your script as `bash -x scriptname` (and post output here) this can give you (and us) an idea of what is happening

Comment: please checkout the output @Yury Nevinitsin

Comment: Why do you redirect output with `>a.txt 1>/dev/null` and delete the file afterwards? There will not be any output left for `>/dev/null`. Just remove the `>a.txt` and `>>a.txt` and `rm a.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

After reading bash -x output I can give you a rewrite of the script

```
#!/bin/bash
                                               # Here I remark changes

SCRIPT="$(readlink -f "$0")"
SCRIPTFILE="$(basename "$SCRIPT")"             # get name of the file (not full path)
SCRIPTPATH="$(dirname "$SCRIPT")"
SCRIPTNAME="$0"
ARGS=( "$@" )                                  # fixed to make array of args (see below)
BRANCH="master"

self_update() {
    cd "$SCRIPTPATH"
    git fetch

                                               # in the next line
                                               # 1. added double-quotes (see below)
                                               # 2. removed grep expression so
                                               # git-diff will check only script
                                               # file
    [ -n "$(git diff --name-only "origin/$BRANCH" "$SCRIPTFILE")" ] && {
        echo "Found a new version of me, updating myself..."
        git pull --force
        git checkout "$BRANCH"
        git pull --force
        echo "Running the new version..."
        cd -                                   # return to original working dir
        exec "$SCRIPTNAME" "${ARGS[@]}"

        # Now exit this old instance
        exit 1
    }
    echo "Already the latest version."
}
self_update
echo “some code”
```

**Below 1**. `ARGS="( $@ )"` definitely should be `ARGS=( "$@" )`, otherwise after update script is executed with `'( -h )'` argument instead of `-h` (in general, it is executed with all arguments concatenated in a single string, i.e. you run it as `/opt/script/firstScript -a -b -c`, and after update it runs as `/opt/script/firstScript '( -a -b -c )'`

**Below 2**. Double quotes are necessary around `$(...)`, otherwise `[ -n` uses `]` as input argument and returns true because it is not empty (while the empty output of `git-diff|grep` is ignored in argument list of `[ -n`) (**That was the loop cause**)

Comment: SCRIPTPATH="$(dirname "$SCRIPT")" ---Do you mean SCRIPTPATH="$(dirname "$SCRIPTFILE")" and I added git reset --hard and chmod +x "$SCRIPTNAME" but still go into a loop

Comment: you are right, updated answer with proper SCRIPTPATH. In my environment it worked. Can you run it with bash -x again and post output again? (maybe use pastebin.com for it not to flood here)

Comment: would recommend
`branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`
rather than hard-coding the branch name

Comment: and `UPSTREAM=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{upstream})` and then use `"$UPSTREAM"` in place of "origin/$BRANCH"

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons that the script might fail to update itself. Putting aside the "why" for a minute, consider using an "double-invoke" guard based on environment variable. It will prevent repeated attempt to update.

```
self_update() {
    [ "$UPDATE_GUARD" ] && return
    export UPDATE_GUARD=YES

    cd $SCRIPTPATH
    git fetch

    [ -n $(git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH | grep $SCRIPTNAME) ] && {
        echo "Found a new version of me, updating myself..."
        git pull --force
        git checkout $BRANCH
        git pull --force
        echo "Running the new version..."
        exec "$SCRIPTNAME" "${ARGS[@]}"

        # Now exit this old instance
        exit 1
    }
    echo "Already the latest version."
}
```

Also, consider changing the `self_update` to go back into the original cwd, if it might have impact on running the script.

Comment: it updates but continues using old code "not the updated code" and does not pass args. Please explain more about what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that you have not set up upstream tracking for the current branch. Then `git fetch` does nothing at all.  Try

```
git fetch origin master
```

instead (assuming that's the upstream and branch you want).

You also don't seem to understand the significance of the `exec` in the code you found. This will replace the currently executing script with the updated version and start running it from the start.  There is no way that

```
update_code
echo "some stuff"
```

will `echo "some stuff"` right after updating itself. Instead, it will execute itself again, hopefully then this time with an updated version of the code.

However,

```
[ -n $(git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH | grep $SCRIPTNAME) ]
```

is a really roundabout and potentially brittle construct. You are asking whether `grep` returned any (non-empty) output ... but obviously, `grep` itself is a tool for checking whether there are any matches. Additionally, using `SCRIPTNAME` here is brittle -- if the script was invoked with a path like `/home/you/work/script/update_self_test` that's what `SCRIPTNAME` contains, but `git diff` will only output a relative path (`script/update_self_test` in this case if `/home/you/work` is the Git working directory) and so the `grep` will fail. (In your `bash -x` transcript, you see `grep /opt/script/firstScript` -- that's exactly this bug.)

Since you are in the directory of the file already, I would advocate

```
git diff --name-only origin/master "$(basename "$SCRIPTNAME")"
```

which will print nothing if the file has not changed, and the file name of this single file if it has.  Unfortunately, this does not set its exit code to indicate success or failure (I guess it's hard to define that here, though the traditional convention is for the regular `diff` command to report a non-zero exit code when there are differences) but we can use

```
git diff --name-only origin/master "$(basename "$SCRIPTNAME")" | grep -q . &&
```

for the whole conditional. (Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642))

Finally, your own attempt has another problem as well. Besides failing to `exec`, you have ambiguous redirects. You try to send stuff to the file `a.txt` but you are also trying to send the same stuff to `/dev/null`.  Which is it?  Make up your mind.

For what it's worth,

```
echo testing >a.txt 1>/dev/null
```

sends `testing` to `/dev/null`; it first redirects standard output to `a.txt` but then updates the redirect, so you simply end up creating an empty file in `a.txt` if it didn't already exist.

Eventually, you should probably also switch to lower case for your private variables; but I see that you simply copied the wrong convention from the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the answers here, and some of my own requirements:

- timeout git(!)
- silent, no output
- stash local changes
- Recursive loop trap
- always use origin/main
- use git diff exitcodes instead of output

I made the following version:

```
#!/bin/bash
                                               # Here I remark changes
#
SCRIPT="$(readlink -f "$0")"
SCRIPTFILE="$(basename "$SCRIPT")"             # get name of the file (not full path)
SCRIPTPATH="$(dirname "$SCRIPT")"
SCRIPTNAME="$0"
ARGS=( "$@" )                                  # fixed to make array of args (see below)

self_update() {
    [ "$UPDATE_GUARD" ] && return
    export UPDATE_GUARD=YES
    
    cd "$SCRIPTPATH"
    timeout 1s git fetch --quiet

                                               # in the next line
                                               # 1. added double-quotes (see below)
                                               # 2. removed grep expression so
                                               # git-diff will check only script
                                               # file

    timeout 1s git diff --quiet --exit-code "origin/main" "$SCRIPTFILE"
    [ $? -eq 1 ] && {
        #echo "Found a new version of me, updating myself..."
        if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ];  # opposite is -z
        then 
            git stash push -m 'local changes stashed before self update' --quiet
        fi
        git pull --force --quiet
        git checkout main --quiet
        git pull --force --quiet
        #echo "Running the new version..."
        cd - > /dev/null                        # return to original working dir
        exec "$SCRIPTNAME" "${ARGS[@]}"

        # Now exit this old instance
        exit 1
    }
    #echo "Already the latest version."
}
self_update
echo "some code2"
```

Answer (score -1):

Your script launches the 'self_update' bash function, whitch itself calls `exec "$SCRIPTNAME" "${ARGS[@]}"`.
But if I read well, `$SCRIPTNAME` is your script.

Your script will keep calling itself recursively.
That's why you are looping.

Have you considered running your script with something like [cron](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) instead of making it call itself ?

Edit:
Also the git command in the test, `git diff --name-only origin/$BRANCH` would respond with line containing the script file  if you had local changes in it, and loop forever.

Comment: I thought too that this is the reason, but the OP tried to avoid this case by guarding the recursive call with the `if`... That's why asked for the output of the `grep` in my comment.

Comment: I'll edit my answer with another remark on the git command: it answers `true` when there are local changes in the script and will loop forever.

Comment: So do you mean I should add cron job in my script that schedule one Time Task to exit my script and replcae old code with new one and pass user args and re-run my script with the now code?

Comment: @abdulr7man : Don't get the question. _adding a **cron** job to a script_ does not make sense. You can define a new cron job which calls a script of your liking, but I don't see what a **cron** job has to do with your use case.

Comment: @abdulr7man you don't add a cron job to ths script, you run your script using cron. this job is then ran periodically and you avoid the recursive call, which is dangerous (so dangerous as if you make a mistake in the [ ] test your program loops).